# Is there a pandas/numpy function to spread an integer across subsequent zeroes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to turn, for example, the following string:

```
"3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0"
```

into:

```
"1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5".
```

So each integer is divided into even parts and split between it's own position, and the following zeroes.

I am primarily an R user, and have accomplished this in `R` with:

```
x <- c(0,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0)

ave(x,cumsum(x))
```

I am having difficulty finding a similar simple flow in Python, does one exist?

Comment: Your question is on string, but your R example is on numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunately there is no such functions in pandas that I am aware of, though you can use `groupby()` for this :

```
s="3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0"
ser=pd.Series(s.split(',')).astype(int)
#this splits the string and converts to a series
```

Now, we segregate the series into groups(Thanks @QuangHoang) and we take a `cumsum()` of the same. Check below for output of cumsum. Then using groupby we transform the series to `mean`

Last we add a `.tolist()` and `.join()` them since you wanted the output as a string.

```
','.join(ser.groupby(ser.cumsum()).transform('mean').astype(str).tolist())
#or ','.join(ser.groupby((ser.ne(0)).cumsum()).transform('mean').astype(str).tolist())
```

---

```
'1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5'
```

Output for `cumsum()`:

```
ser.cumsum()

0    3
1    3
2    3
3    5
4    5
5    5
6    5
7    6
8    6
```

Comment: In the light of OP's R code, we might not need `.ne(0)`, just `groupby(ser.cumsum())` is enough.

Comment: @QuangHoang you are correct again ;) thanks and I have updated the solution now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to approach this using numpy:

```
s = "3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0" 
a = np.fromstring(s, sep=',')
# array([3., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.])
# Find the length of consecutive 0s in a
d = np.diff(np.r_[False, a==0, False].astype(int))
zero_len = np.flatnonzero(d==-1) - np.flatnonzero(d==1)
# array([2, 3, 1], dtype=int64)
# normalize the values and repeat as many times as zero_len+1
np.repeat(a[a!=0]/(zero_len+1), zero_len+1)
```

Which gives:

```
array([1. , 1. , 1. , 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Data from `anky_91`

```
ser.mask(ser==0).ffill()/ser.groupby(ser.ne(0).cumsum()).transform('count')
Out[1242]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    0.5
4    0.5
5    0.5
6    0.5
7    0.5
8    0.5
dtype: float64
```